# What should I do to run CloudLinux on DigitalOcean?

Tags: system-installation, webserver

I used CentOS as a DO Droplet platform. Now I want to use CloudLinux.
As it turned out, DO currently doesn't support custom kernels, so how to do it? How to configure WHM?

Answer (score 0):

It is different from when you install on a server other than Digital Ocean. I assume we already downloaded PuTTy (I am on my Windows 7). To install use the commands below:

```
wget http://repo.cloudlinux.com/cloudlinux/sources/cln/cpanel2cl
sh cpanel2cl -k (masukan key yang diberikan oleh cloud linux)
yum install lvemanager
reboot
/scripts/easyapache –build
```

In the process you will be prompted to enter "y" in the "y / N" option to execute special commands for CloudLinux to be installed in DigitalOcean.

The installation process is complete, now login to WHM, then navigate to "server configuration" - there is already a new menu called "Cloud Linux LVE Manager". That menu will inform you what to do in the existing account in the VPS.

For more information go here: https://docs.cloudlinux.com/index.html?digitalocean.html